# Twilio PHP SDK / API - Listing Messages From Multiple Phone Numbers

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am currently using version 4 of the Twilio PHP Helper Library and list messages using the following call:

```
$twilio = new Twilio();
$twilio->account->messages->getPage(0, 300, array(
    'From' => $myPhoneNumber
));
```

I am able to get all incoming messages from a specific phone number with the above.

Is there anyway to search for all incoming messages from multiple phone numbers?  Something like:

```
$twilio->account->messages->getPage(0, 300, array(
    'From' => array($myPhoneNumberOne, $myMyPhoneNumberTwo, $myPhoneNumberThree)
));
```

If this isn't possible with the V4 version of the library, I am open to using version 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately today the underlying REST API does not support this type of searching but it's certainly an interesting idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This would be a great feature to have.  I currently have a "chat" app that allows users to send and receive SMS messages on a web client.  The chat app allows you to search for a particular keyword.  It returns all users who match that keyword.  For every user that is found, I have to invoke 2 calls (one for incoming messages and one for outgoing messages) corresponding to that number.  If the search returns a few dozen records, it would have to make upwards of up to 100 calls (2 per record).  This slows down the search speed quite a bit.  Any way of adding this as a feature request?